# Fast query when executed on SQL Server Express, slow when executed on Standard?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, sql-server-2019

We are observing a strange problem with SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition.  We have an admittedly complex query that involves a temporary table.  It runs just fine on SQL Server 2019 **Express** (less than 1 second) but takes more than 13 minutes (!) on SQL Server 2019 **Standard** edition (at hardware parity - 2 vCPU, 8 GB RAM - and against the same data set).

This happens consistently, regardless of the OS / environment:

- *Cloud SQL For SQL Server* (Google Cloud's managed SQL Server): around 25 minutes
- SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition on Ubuntu Linux: 13 minutes
- SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition on Windows Server (using GCP ready-to-use image): 13 minutes

#### Notes

- **During that time we can observe one CPU core utilised at 100% steadily.**

  - Other cores are idle.
- If we comment out any two `AND` conditions from the `WHERE` clause of the query, **it executes in 1 or 2 seconds everywhere** (GCP Cloud SQL, SQL Server Standard editions).

#### The query

```sql
Declare
 @SubscriberId           INT                = 100,    
 @UserName               NVARCHAR(10)       = 'testUser',    
 @SiteId                 INT                = 10240,    
 @Category               NVARCHAR(MAX)      = '',    
 @AssetStatus            NVARCHAR(50)       = '',    
 @Upcoming               NVARCHAR(5)        = '',    
 @OverDue                NVARCHAR(5)        = '',    
 @ActionStatus           NVARCHAR(5)        = '',    
 @NextInspectionFromDate NVARCHAR(10)       = '',    
 @NextInspectionToDate   NVARCHAR(10)       = '',    
 @LastInspectionFromDate NVARCHAR(10)       = '',    
 @LastInspectionToDate   NVARCHAR(10)       = '',    
 @QuickSearch            NVARCHAR(MAX)      = '',    
 @Latitude               NVARCHAR(50)       = '',    
 @Longitude              NVARCHAR(50)       = '',    
 @AssignToFromDate       NVARCHAR(10)       = '',    
 @AssignToToDate         NVARCHAR(10)       = '',    
 @IsExpired              NVARCHAR(1)        = '',     
 @ExpiredFromDate        NVARCHAR(10)       = '',    
 @ExpiredToDate          NVARCHAR(10)       = '',    
 @AssetCategory          NVARCHAR(10)       = '2,3',    
 @APKID                  VARCHAR(MAX)       = '',    
 @CopyID                 NVARCHAR(500)      = '' 
    
    --Dynamic Label for Asset Status based on UserPersona --   
    Create Table #tmpAssetStatus (AssetStatusID INT, AssetStatusName NVARCHAR(100), ShortcutCode NVARCHAR(10), BaseAssetStatus INT, ColorCode NVARCHAR(20))   
    
    Insert into #tmpAssetStatus   
    Select * From ufn_RefAssetStatus(@SubscriberId, @Username)   
    
    DECLARE @Latitute DECIMAL(12, 9), @Longitute DECIMAL(12, 9), @SitePoint GEOGRAPHY, @GeoRadius INT   
    DECLARE @NoDate VARCHAR(10)= '1901/01/01'      
        
    IF ISNULL(@AssetStatus,'') = ''    
    BEGIN   
       SET @AssetStatus = '1,2,6,7'   
    END   
    
    SET @SitePoint = geography ::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326)   
    SET @GeoRadius =   
    (   
        SELECT GeoRadius   
        FROM SysPerson   
        WHERE Username = @UserName    
    )   
    DECLARE @InspectionInterval INT, @AlertInterval INT   
    SELECT
       @InspectionInterval = InspectionInterval,    
       @AlertInterval = AlertInterval   
    FROM SysSubscriber   
    WHERE ID = @SubscriberID   
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL   
    DROP TABLE #Temp   
    
    SELECT A.Id AS AssetId,    
       AssetName,    
       CAST(A.Description AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS Description,   
       NULLIF(CAST(LastInspectionDate AS DATE),'1900-01-01') AS LastInspectionDate,    
       CompanyID,    
       SerialNumber,    
       CustomID,        
       NULLIF(CAST(NextInspectionDate AS DATE),'1900-01-01') AS NextInspectionDate,    
       ManufacturerName,    
       ModelNumber,    
       CAST(' ' AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Result,    
       ISNULL(A.TemplateName, '') AS TemplateName,    
       ISNULL(a.IsKit, 0) AS IsKit,    
       ISNULL(A.MasterAssetID, 0) AS MasterAssetID,    
       A.IsInspectionRequired,   
       CASE   
       WHEN JobCardStatus = 2   
       THEN NULL   
       ELSE A.JobCardID   
       END AS JobCardID,    
       A.AssetStatus,    
    ISNULL(A.ItemTypeID, 0) ItemTypeID, 
       C.name AS DeviceTypeName,    
       D.name AS SubType,    
       (CASE   
        WHEN A.AssetStatus IN(1, 2)   
         AND DATEDIFF(d, A.NextInspectionDate, GETDATE() + @AlertInterval) BETWEEN 0 AND @AlertInterval   
         AND A.NextInspectionDate IS NOT NULL   
         AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.NextInspectionDate, 111) > @NoDate   
        THEN 1   
        ELSE 0   
    END) AS NextInspectionDateFlag,    
       (CASE   
        WHEN A.AssetStatus IN(1, 2)   
         AND DATEDIFF(d, A.NextInspectionDate, GETDATE()) > 0   
         AND A.NextInspectionDate IS NOT NULL   
         AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.nextinspectiondate, 111) > @NoDate   
        THEN 1   
        ELSE 0   
    END) AS DueFlag,    
       NULLIF(CAST(AssignedDueDate as Date),'1900-01-01') AS AssignedDueDate,    
       (CASE   
        WHEN((A.UsageCount >= A.Servicelife   
      AND A.AssetStatus IN(1, 2)   
      AND A.UsageCount IS NOT NULL   
      AND A.Servicelife IS NOT NULL)   
         OR (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), A.ExpiryDate) < 0   
         AND A.ExpiryDate IS NOT NULL))   
        THEN 1   
        ELSE 0   
    END) AS IsExpiry,    
       IsKitSchemaCompleted,    
       A.TemplateKey, 
       NULLIF(CAST(DateofFirstuse AS DATE),'1900-01-01') AS DateofFirstuse,   
       A.SiteName,   
       A.APKCategory as Category,   
       A.GenericID,   
       A.JobName as ProjectName,   
       A.[Standard],   
       A.ProductRating as LoadRating,   
       A.PurchaseOrderNumber,   
       A.Batch as Batch,   
       A.AssignedTo,   
       A.SubscriberName,   
       A.AssignedMobileNumber,   
       A.KitAssetName as KitName,   
       A.InspectionCalendar,   
       A.InspectionPeriod,   
       A.InspectionPeriodCount,   
       A.InspectionPeriodUnit,   
       A.UsageCount,   
       A.ServiceLife,   
       CAST(A.AnniversaryDate AS DATE) AS AnniversaryDate,   
       CAST(A.ExpiryDate AS DATE) AS ExpiryDate,   
       CAST(A.ManufactureDate AS DATE) AS ManufacturedDate,   
       A.Dimensions,   
       T.AssetStatusName,   
       T.ShortcutCode,   
       T.BaseAssetStatus,    
       T.ColorCode,   
       case
           when A.InspectionPeriod=1 then 'Daily'           
           when A.InspectionPeriod=2 then 'Weekly'           
           when A.InspectionPeriod=3 then 'Monthly'           
           when A.InspectionPeriod=4 then 'Yearly'            
           when A.InspectionPeriod=5 then 'Number'           
           when A.InspectionPeriod=6 then 'Quarterly'           
           when A.InspectionPeriod=7 then 'Half Yearly'           
       End as InspectionCycle,   
       InspectorDetails.FirstName+' '+InspectorDetails.LastName as InspectorName,   
       ReviewerDetails.FirstName+' '+ReviewerDetails.LastName as ReviewerName,   
       ISNULL(A.PurchasePrice,0.00) as PurchasePrice, 
       A.AssetLatitute as Latitude, 
       A.AssetLongitute as Longitude 
    INTO #Temp   
    FROM ScxAssetView A   
     LEFT OUTER JOIN insTemplateLatestView B ON A.TemplateKey = B.TemplateKey   
     LEFT OUTER JOIN RefItemType C ON A.ItemTypeID = C.ID   
     LEFT OUTER JOIN RefItemSubType D ON A.ItemSubTypeID = D.ID   
     Left Join sysPerson InspectorDetails on InspectorDetails.Username=A.Inspector    
     Left Join sysPerson ReviewerDetails on ReviewerDetails.Username=A.Reviewer    
     Left Join #tmpAssetStatus T ON T.BaseAssetStatus = A.AssetStatus   
    WHERE A.SubscriberID = @SubscriberId   
      AND A.SiteID = ISNULL(@SiteId, A.SiteID)   
     AND A.APKActive = 1   
     AND ((@AssetStatus = '')   
      OR AssetStatus IN (SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AssetStatus, ',')))   
     AND ((@Category = '')   
      OR A.ItemTypeID IN (SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Category, ',')))   
     AND ((@Upcoming = '')   
      OR (AssetStatus IN (SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,6,7', ','))   
      AND DATEDIFF(d, NextInspectionDate, GETDATE() + @AlertInterval) BETWEEN 0 AND @AlertInterval   
      AND NextInspectionDate IS NOT NULL   
      AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NextInspectionDate, 111) > @NoDate))   
     AND ((@Overdue = '')   
      OR (AssetStatus IN (SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,6,7', ','))   
      AND DATEDIFF(d, NextInspectionDate, GETDATE()) > 0   
      AND NextInspectionDate IS NOT NULL   
      AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NextInspectionDate, 111) > @NoDate))   
     AND ((@NextInspectionFromDate = ''   
       AND @NextInspectionToDate = '')   
      OR (CAST(NextInspectionDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@NextInspectionFromDate AS DATE) AND CAST(@NextInspectionToDate AS DATE)))   
     AND ((@LastInspectionFromDate = ''   
       AND @LastInspectionToDate = '')   
      OR (CAST(LastInspectionDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@LastInspectionFromDate AS DATE) AND CAST(@LastInspectionToDate AS DATE)))   
     AND ((@AssignToFromDate = ''   
       AND @AssignToToDate = '')   
      OR (CAST(AssignedDueDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@AssignToFromDate AS DATE) AND CAST(@AssignToToDate AS DATE)))   
     AND (@QuickSearch = ''   
      OR (A.AssetName LIKE '%' + @QuickSearch + '%'))   
     AND (@QuickSearch = ''   
      OR (AssignedTo LIKE '%' + @QuickSearch + '%'))   
     AND 1 = CASE   
         WHEN @Latitude = ''   
          OR @Longitude = ''   
          OR @Latitude IS NULL   
          OR @Longitude IS NULL   
         THEN 1   
         WHEN AssetLatitute IS NOT NULL   
          AND AssetLongitute IS NOT NULL   
          AND AssetLatitute != 0   
          AND AssetLongitute != 0   
          AND @SitePoint.STDistance(geography::Point(AssetLatitute, AssetLongitute, 4326)) <= @GeoRadius   
         THEN 1   
     END   
    AND ((@IsExpired = '')   
     OR (IsExpiry = @IsExpired))   
    AND ((@ExpiredFromDate = ''   
      AND @ExpiredToDate = '')   
     OR (CAST(ExpiryDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@ExpiredFromDate AS DATE) AND CAST(@ExpiredToDate AS DATE)))   
    AND APKCategory IN (SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AssetCategory, ','))   
    AND (@APKID = ''   
     OR A.ID IN (SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@APKID, ',')))   
    AND (@CopyID = '' OR A.CopyID IN (SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@CopyID, ',')))   
    ORDER BY A.ID DESC                                         
   
    Select * From #Temp
 
    Drop Table #tmpAssetStatus
```

We tried multiple times and the results were consistent.  Of course we expect the query to take more or less the same time when executed on SQL Server 2019 Standard.  Any pointers will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Is this a procedure? With clauses like `((@IsExpired = '') OR (IsExpiry = @IsExpired))` do you have a `RECOMPILE` is the procedure's definition, as you're not using `RECOMPILE` in your `OPTION` clause. If you aren't enforcing recompiling you could end up with some very *wrong* cached plans.

Comment: Why are you doing things like `CAST(AssignedDueDate AS DATE)` as well? Is `AssignedDueDate ` *not* already a date and time data type? Why define *all* your variables as an `nvarchar` when some clearly should be something else, such as `ExpiredFromDate nvarchar(10)` (why is it not a `date`?).

Comment: I would probably rewrite this query to use dynamic sql to only query for parameters actually passed in. Also, i'd probably "unsplit" the STRING_SPLIT things into temporary tables. Perhaps it's spending a lot of time compiling it, you can get the query plan for it and it should have some properties for compile time. Or run set statististics time on

Comment: There is nothing to gain from trying to work out what is different between the different versions. Instead performance tune the slow query, starting with the execution plan.

Comment: Aside... so how do you fit `'testUser1024'` into an `nvarchar(10)`?

Comment: I would suggest that manually calculating `.STDistance()` for the Latitude and Longitude in every row in the table probably isn't the most efficient thing to do.  Spatial indexes will only help you if you store the Latitude and Longitude as a single column of Geography point and use [acceptable query methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview#geography).